# Should components with primitive types be Pure components in most cases?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Should a component with all primitive proptypes be pure in most cases( if not all cases)?

```
    ProductLookupControl.propTypes = {
     selectedProductCode: PropTypes.string,
     dataTestId: PropTypes.string,
     selectedProductName: PropTypes.string,  
     cityCode: PropTypes.string,
     currencyCode: PropTypes.string,    
     disabled: PropTypes.bool    
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if the prop types are primitive, you should *always use pure component*. Pure component is one of the most significant ways to optimize React applications. The usage of Pure Component gives a considerable increase in performance because it reduces the number of render operation in the application.

**When to use Pure Components?**

Suppose you creating a dictionary page in which you display the meaning of all the English words starting with A. Now you can write a component which takes a word and its meaning as props and return a proper view. And suppose you using pagination to display only 10 words at a time and on scroll asking for another 10 words and updating the state of the parent component. Pure Components should be used in this case as it will avoid rendering of all the words which rendered in the previous API request.

Also in cases where you want to use lifecycle methods of Component then we have to use Pure Components as stateless components don't have lifecycle methods.

> **Conclusion**

Pure Components gives a considerable increase in performance because it reduces the number of render operation in the application which is a huge win for complex UI and therefore advised to use if possible. Also, there will be cases where you want to use the lifecycle methods of Component and in such cases, we cannot use stateless components.